# Why Drupal 7 not connecting with with Apache Solr 4.8? Undefined property: error: stdClass::$entity_type in apachesolr_search_process_response()

Tags: php, apache, drupal, solr, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal and Solr development, I am trying to do basic thing, which is connecting Drupal with my Solr on my localhost.
I have Drupal 7 and I have installed Apache Solr module by downloading the module and I have put it in Drupal/sites/all/modules
and I have have downloaded Solr mirror 4.8 and put in different directory, outside my server directory.

According to Apache Solr module installation guide I have to copy the configuration files (solrcofig.xml, schema.xml,portwords.xml) from Apache Solr module and paste them in Solr (replace them with the ones in Solr).
However, Apache Solr module in the following directory 
apachesolr/solr-conf/
has another 3 directories, solr-1.4, solr-3.x, solr-4.x
each one has configuration files, as I am using Apache Solr module 4.8 it seems I should use the configuration files in solr-4.x directory. However, when I use the ones in solr-4.x directory Solr server doesn't start when I run the command

$ java -jar start.jar

I have tried all the configuration files from all the different three directories the only ones on solr-3.x can start Solr server.
Then, I have indexed Solr by run the command

$ java -jar post.jar *.xml

Now, on my site on Drupal I can see there are 32 items, but I cant see any thing on the content, also I checked the connection between Drupal and Solr and it says it is connected. when I search the my website it gives me the following error

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$entity_type in apachesolr_search_process_response() (line 1290 of /anypath/drupal/sites/all/modules/apachesolr/apachesolr_search.module).
any help would be much appreciated. Thanks